# Boolean Algebra, meaning of this sign...?

Tags: boolean-logic

What does the equivalence sign with the small 3 next to it mean... I'm unfamiliar with that sign.

≡<sub>3</sub>

Thanks!

Comment: Not really an SO question but you asked it clearly so +1.

Comment: The link has since died. Do you happen to remember what the image looked like and can reproduce it?

Comment: The selected answer clearly shows the sign I had a question about, but I changed the link to reflect the sign in plain text instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means "is congruent to modulo 3."  For example, 7 ≡<sub>3</sub> 1 because 7 mod 3 = 1 = 1 mod 3.  More formally, a ≡<sub>n</sub> b iff there exists integral c<sub>0</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>, along with an integral k with 0  ≤  k < n, such that a = nc<sub>0</sub> + k and b = nc<sub>1</sub> + k.

Comment: integrals = integers, I guess :D